# BarStyle "dark-content" in StatusBar is not working in IOS (React Native)

Tags: react-native, statusbar

I want that `barStyle` is always be `"dark-content"` in `StatusBar` in IOS. However, I see that text is still switching to white, when phone is in dark mode. Is there any solution to this problem? React Native version is "0.63.4".

```
import {
  Platform,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';


 <StatusBar
          barStyle={Platform.OS === 'ios'? 'dark-content': 'default'}
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem. I removed `basStyle` from the component and wrote instead in `App.js` inside `useEffect()` this code and it started working:

```
useEffect(() => {
    StatusBar.setBarStyle(Platform.OS === 'ios'? 'dark-content': 'default')
}, []);
```